# How do I fake the return of a built-in method in C# unit test?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, testing, tdd, moq

I have a public static method that uses an object of Random class to generate an integer. The integer is then made the index of a List. I want to test the logic of the method while having control over what a random object's Next method returns.

```cs
public class RandomGenerator
  {

    // a static method which produces a random selection from a List
    public static string GetRandomListMember(List<string> anyStringList)
    {
      Random rand = new Random();
      int randomInt = rand.Next(anyStringList.Count);
      return anyStringList[randomInt];
    }
  }
```

From my MSTest file:

```cs
[TestClass]
  public class RandomGeneratorSpec
  {
    [TestMethod]
    public void GetRandomListMember_ListOfStrings()
    {
      List<string> strings = new List<string> { "red", "yellow", "green" }; 

      Mock<Random> mockRandom = new Mock<Random>();
      mockRandom.Setup(rand => rand.Next(strings.Count)).Returns(() => 2); // 2!

      string result = RandomGenerator.GetRandomListMember(strings);

      Assert.AreEqual("green", result);
    }
  }
```

I want mockRandom.Next to return 2 every time it runs in this test. Obviously, this isn't the way to do it. I've been searching through examples, but they all seem to utilize methods on the object and with instance methods instead of static methods.

How do I control what a built-in method returns while unit testing a method that utilizes it?

Comment: You shouldn't have to if you design your code optimally.

Comment: Moq works best with abstractions not static

Comment: If the end goal is to get a list of predictable "random" numbers, an alternative to mocking is to use the seed parameter of the Random class.

Comment: I don't really see the point of your unit test here. If you "fake" the random class, all you really test is if you are able to retrieve an element from the List. A more sensible unit test IMHO would be to validate that the truly randomly picked element is contained in the List you provide in your test.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create your own `Random` class locally with whatever methods you need to redefine from the `System.Random` class.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var rand = new Random();
        int next = rand.Next(); // uses my local Random class.
    }
}

class Random
{
    public int Next() => 2;
}
```

Comment: This was more of an explicit answer to the question, but I'm definitely learning from Nkosi's answer below.

Answer (score 4):

Consider refactoring to allow a more maintainable design

```
public class RandomGenerator {
    private readonly Random random;

    public RandomGenerator(Random random = default(Random)) {
        this.random = random ?? new Random();
    }

    public string GetRandomListMember(List<string> anyStringList) {
        int randomInt = random.Next(anyStringList.Count);
        return anyStringList[randomInt];
    }
}
```

Which allows more flexibility with using and testing the subject class

```
[TestClass]
public class RandomGeneratorSpec {
    [TestMethod]
    public void GetRandomListMember_ListOfStrings() {
        //Arrange
        List<string> strings = new List<string> { "red", "yellow", "green" };
        string expected = "green";
        Mock<Random> mockRandom = new Mock<Random>();
        mockRandom.Setup(rand => rand.Next(strings.Count)).Returns(() => 2); // 2!
        var subject = new RandomGenerator(mockRandom.Object);

        //Act
        string actual = subject.GetRandomListMember(strings);

        //Assert
        Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
    }
}
```

Ideally if this generator is to be used as a service, it should have its own abstraction

```
public interface IRandomGenerator {
    string GetRandomListMember(List<string> anyStringList);
}

public class RandomGenerator : IRandomGenerator {
    //...omitted for brevity
}
```

so that it can be injected explicitly where needed and not be used statically as a tightly coupled dependency that can be considered a code smell.

Answer (score 0):

An example of my suggestion in the comment:

```
[TestClass]
public class RandomGeneratorSpec
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void GetRandomListMember_ListOfStrings()
    {
        List<string> strings = new List<string> { "red", "yellow", "green" }; 

        string result = RandomGenerator.GetRandomListMember(strings);

        Assert.IsTrue(strings.Contains(result));
    }
}
```